# Seagate expansion format for mac

Tags: macos, mac, external-disk, disk-format

I buy a new one. I am trying to format support for my mac air. I tried all the way by seeing some procedures showing on the youtube even no luck.

I disk is appearing like this:

[image]

Need help, please

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If you link to the article you followed - it might help someone suggest a better one. Also - why not click erase or partition and set up the drive for Mac?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://superuser.com/questions/1291261/seagate-expansion-format-for-mac